# Display information according to the <selected> location

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make like a simple printer manager so i will be able to see all of my printers statuses so far i have managed to display all the data now i want to organize it by location and the error i'm getting is: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined maybe the reason is that  [(ngModel)] that it is not working properly i think
thank you.

[image: example]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Values } from '../Models/Values';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-value',
  templateUrl: './value.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
})


export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedPrinter: Values;
  values: any;
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();


  }

  getValues() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values/').subscribe(response => {
      this.values = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

```html
<H2>Print Manager</H2>



<div id="selectCompanyDiv">

  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
    <label for="">Select location</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter">
      <option *ngFor="let each of values " [ngValue]="each">{{each.location}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>


  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let value of values" id="mainDiv">
      <!-- <p>{{value.id}},{{value.hostName}},{{value.location}},{{value.manufacturer}},{{value.ip}}</p> -->

      <span>Hostname: {{value.hostName}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>Location: {{value.location}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>Manufacturer: {{value.manufacturer}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>IP: {{value.ip}}</span>
      <br>
      <h2>{{value.location}}</h2>


      <div>

        <div *ngIf="value.hostName==='BROTHERJ480'" class="outerFrame">
          <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://'+value.ip+'/general/status.html')" id="inneriframej480" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="value.hostName==='Brother6530DW'" class="outerFrame">
          <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://'+value.ip+'/general/status.html')" id="inneriframeBrother6530DW" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share also what you are getting from api ? and what do u want to to with select method? It is doing nothing for now

Comment: im getting json of : id ,hostname ,location, ip and manufacturer

Comment: What do u want to do with select element?

Comment: I'm trying to get the selected printer by location, for example if i select kitchen so i will only see the kitchen printer

Comment: Okey I added answer you need a if condition that check if value is equals with selected value @Chen Tmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need if condition to show hide related to selected value

in component change

```
selectedPrinter: string="Bed Room";
```

then in html

```
<H2>Print Manager</H2>
<div id="selectCompanyDiv">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
    <label for="">Select location</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter">
      <option *ngFor="let each of values " value="{{each.location}}">{{each.location}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
<div>
<div *ngFor="let value of values" id="mainDiv">
    <div *ngIf="value.location===selectedPrinter">
      <span>Hostname: {{value.hostName}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>Location: {{value.location}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>Manufacturer: {{value.manufacturer}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>IP: {{value.ip}}</span>
      <br>
      <h2>{{value.location}}</h2>
      <div>
        <div *ngIf="value.hostName==='BROTHERJ480'" class="outerFrame">
          <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://'+value.ip+'/general/status.html')" id="inneriframej480" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="value.hostName==='Brother6530DW'" class="outerFrame">
          <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://'+value.ip+'/general/status.html')" id="inneriframeBrother6530DW" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div *ngIf="value.hostName===selectedPrinter.hostName"> i got red underline under hostName its suppose to be HostName(like in my model) and when i change it to HostName i get Cannot read property 'HostName' of undefined

Comment: Okey I updated answer I missed your value of selectedPrinter. It is a location value @Chen Tmv

Comment: Yeah now i dont see the iframes at all not even when clicked....xD

Comment: Yes! finally it works! thank you so much btw do u know why the select is blank?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the selected value, at the time of selection using `ngModelChange` event and can perform the desired functionality (based on the selected Printer value). If this is not the issue, please elaborate the issue.